# How can I get the page title into a Django HttpResponse object

Tags: django-views

I have a Django view that displays a pdf file

```
# views.py

def get(self, request, recipe_pk):
    """Display a recipe as a pdf."""
    recipe = Recipe.objects.get(pk=recipe_pk)
    recipe_file_path = _get_recipe_path(recipe.file_name.name)
    with open(recipe_file_path, 'rb+') as f_recipe:
        response = HttpResponse(f_recipe.read(), content_type='application/pdf')
        return response
    pdf.closed
```

This works fine but the *recipe_pk* appears in the page title

I have got the recipe record in the view and would like too use *recipe.name* as the title

Is there any way I can send the more friendly title?

Comment: With a slug? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/glossary/#term-slug

Comment: Thanks. I don't see how that would work - I've updated my question to show what I want in the title

Comment: for a PDF file the browser will look for the title of that pdf file (the "metadata"). So if that is missing, it falls back to the URL.

Comment: Ahhh. I'll try that then

Comment: Perfect do you want to create an answer I can accept

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Willem Van Onsem I have solved it.

> for a PDF file the browser will look for the title of that pdf file (the "metadata"). So if that is missing, it falls back to the URL

Instead of passing the *recipe.pk* in the url, I pass *recipe.name*

```
def get(self, request, recipe_name):
    """Display a recipe as a pdf."""
    recipe = Recipe.objects.get(name=recipe_name)
    recipe_file_path = _get_recipe_path(recipe.file_name.name)
    with open(recipe_file_path, 'rb+') as f_recipe:
        response = HttpResponse(f_recipe.read(), content_type='application/pdf')
        return response
```

Perfect!